# How does Hazelcast MapLoader handle concurrent requests for the same key

Tags: concurrent-programming, hazelcast

Assume that I've implemented storage & loading interfaces and concurrent requests arrived for a key that is not present in the map.

Does Hazelcast ensure that the loader will be called only once for these concurrent requests on the same key OR do I have to handle that case in my loader implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for external locks. Map operations are atomic including mapstore operations.